# Python private variables in a class

Tags: python

I was reading about private variables and functions in Python and I managed to get almost everything except one thing.

Is it recommended to write underscore before variables defined inside a function?

Here is the code so it can be more clear:

**Version 1:**

```
class House():

    def __init__(self):

        self.color = "RED"
        self._discount_coefficient = 0.8

    def get_total_charges(self, json_from_communal_company):

        _water_price        = json_from_communal_company["waterPrice"]
        _electricity_price  = json_from_communal_company["electricityPrice"]

        _total_charges = self._discount_coefficient * (_water_price + _electricity_price)

        return _total_charges
```

**Version 2:**

```
class House():

    def __init__(self):

        self.color = "RED"
        self._discount_coefficient = 0.8

    def get_total_charges(self, json_from_communal_company):

        water_price        = json_from_communal_company["waterPrice"]
        electricity_price  = json_from_communal_company["electricityPrice"]

        total_charges = self._discount_coefficient * (water_price + electricity_price)

        return total_charges
```

I know that variable `_discount_coefficient` needs to have underscore, but I am not sure if variables `water_price`, `electricity_price` and `total_charges` should have underscore or not.

Can someone tell me which version is better and why?

Comment: Where did you read the recommendation about prefixing an underscore, and what does that source suggest regarding *where*?

Comment: I got that recommendation at dozens of different places like some Q&A sites, tutorial sites, etc.
One of them is this question at StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes).
In those articles I managed to get that attributes and functions which should not be accessed outside of the class should have underscore as prefix.

But the thing which confused me was about variables declared inside functions of a class. I could nowhere find if they should have underscore or not so I wrote this question.

Comment: You are making the exact decision in the correct tense. The document to refer to is the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) on *special forms using leading or trailing underscores*.

Comment: I read PEP 8 before I started searching elsewhere, but there it is only written this about leading underscores: "_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore."

Exact case which I wrote in the question was not mentioned.

Comment: `Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables.` (→ do not use this for function/method local variables.)

Comment: I read this part, but somehow I didn't notice this. Thank you for clearing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python object names, a single leading underscore denotes *private* status, like you said.
Unlike other languages, this is not enforced however.
It is only a (strong) suggestion for users of your code not to use these objects.

This could be internal variables, like your `self._discount_coefficient`.
For example, maybe you implement a `@property` that secrectly stores something in `self._discount_coefficient`, but for the calling code, you need to enforce an invariant (in this case, maybe `0 <= self._discount_coefficient <= 1`).
This way, users can only set the `discount_coefficient` instance attribute (notice no underscore) to be within `0` and `1`, otherwise an error is thrown.
Nothing keeps people from directly mingling with `self._discount_coefficient`, however.
Therefore, the convention of underscores; basically a contract where all guarantees you make about your code are void if private objects are modified directly.

Having said all that (which you probably heard of already), it becomes clear that users of your `House` class can never directly access the variables inside your method anyway.
They either access `get_total_charges` as a whole, or nothing.
The decision is therefore to either hide `get_total_charges` as a whole, if it is private, or leave it like in your case.

`water_price`, `electricity_price` and `total_charges` are only temporary variables and tossed the moment the function returns.
They are never relevant to the entire private/public debate because they are never seen from calling code.
If you assigned any of them as instance attributes via `self`, you would have to decide for or against a leading underscore.

As it is, Version 2 looks fine.
As for remaining style, `House()` can just be `House` and the equal signs before `json_from_communal_company` should not be aligned (looks fine now but is a maintenance nightmare).

Comment: "water_price, electricity_price and total_charges are only temporary variables and tossed the moment the function returns. They are never relevant to the entire private/public debate because they are never seen from calling code. If you assigned any of them as instance attributes via self, you would have to decide for or against a leading underscore." - This explains everything. Great answer.